# How to display the date with second and minutes in tooltip

Tags: kendo-ui

```
I have a doubt in Kendo chart tool tip .That is how to display the date  with time format .I have a field    time: `2013-02-13 16:58:07`,
```

some thing like this so when i am reading in tool tip template i am
 calling the field as

> tooltip: {
>      visible: true,
>       template: '**#= category #** 
> ,
>       font: '11px Trebuchet MS'
>     }

In tool tip it was showing as **fri feb 01 2013 00:00:00 gmt+0530(indian standard time)****

How can I change that and display only  `2013-02-13 16:58:07` using remote data

```
I used dataitem in local data it was working fine but with remote data i am getting as undefined.
tooltip: {
                            visible: true,
                            format: "{0}",
                            template: 'DATE:#= dataItem.time<br/>'

                        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to bind the date and time value

Comment: tooltip: {
   visible: true,
   template: "#= dataItem.name # - #= dataItem.date #"
} I configured tool tip .But the tool tip is displaying the first value of the data and remaining all are showing as undefined .can any one please tell me why this situation will occur.I am using remote data.

Comment: I found that the first value is showing and when ever i i moved the time line to particular date then it was showing all the values. how to rectify this problem.and need to dispaly all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the timeformat,this is from ww3c:

```
var d=new Date();
var n=d.toISOString();
```

And this is the result:

```
2013-02-28T07:41:04.188Z
```

Also try to read this:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format